# How can i copy the visual content of a window and put it on a new window in win32 c++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, win32gui

I've read something about GetDIBits or BitBlt but i do not understand them.

That could be because i don't understand how Windows actually handles graphics on windows. It would be perfect if someone could refer me to a page where i could learn about these things! :)

Comment: well, what are you trying to do?

Comment: For example if i have the calculator window handle i would like to copy all the visual content of that window and do an exact same copy of that window but in another window handle that my program have made!

Comment: I think you need to learn gdi a bit. Try look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd145203(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If you want a perfect copy with no editing, you can use a DWM thumbnail.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem using this code in the windows WM_PAINT. It now shows the exact same content as the target window.

```
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc = BeginPaint(MainWindow, &ps);

HDC TargetDC = GetDC(TargetWindow);

RECT rect;
GetWindowRect(TargetWindow, &rect);

BitBlt(hdc,0,0,rect.right-rect.left,rect.bottom-rect.top,TargetDC,0,0,SRCCOPY);

EndPaint(MainWindow, &ps);
```

Comment: Might need some tweaking to work with multiple monitors, espcially if both window are displayed on both monitor (showing half of their content on each).

Answer (score 0):

You might have some luck with sending the window a [WM_PRINTCLIENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd145217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.  This may not work well for windows that use DirectX or OpenGL.

You may have some issues using WM_PRINTCLIENT on systems that have Aero enabled (i.e. when the DWM is active).  If the system DOES have DWM active then it may offer ways of getting at the window backing store but I have not looked into doing that in any great depth before.

Comment: Thanks! But i still don't know how Device Contexts (DC's) work or how i can use them with the WM_PRINTCLIENT message. But still, thanks for the help on the way!

Comment: You shouldn't really need to know how a device context _works_ per se - it is an abstraction of a device which could be a graphics adapter or a bitmap or a printer etc.  it just provides a unified way of drawing on it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to:

1. Get a HWND to the window of which you want the pixels.
2. Create a memory DC of the correct size (check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/224754/Guide-to-Win32-Memory-DC) out).
3. Send a WM_PRINTCLIENT or WM_PAINT to the window whilst supplying your memory DC (not all controls/windows implement this though)
4. Copy the contents of your memory DC to screen

Alternatively for step 3 you can use the DWM or get hacky using the clipboard:

```
void CopyWndToClipboard(CWnd *pWnd)
{
    CBitmap     bitmap;
    CClientDC   dc(pWnd);
    CDC         memDC;
    CRect       rect;

    memDC.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);

    pWnd->GetWindowRect(rect);

    bitmap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(&dc, rect.Width(),rect.Height());

    CBitmap* pOldBitmap = memDC.SelectObject(&bitmap);
    memDC.BitBlt(0, 0, rect.Width(),rect.Height(), &dc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    pWnd->OpenClipboard() ;
    EmptyClipboard() ;
    SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, bitmap.GetSafeHandle()) ;
    CloseClipboard() ;

    memDC.SelectObject(pOldBitmap);
    bitmap.Detach();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i don't have MFC. I need to do it just by using the windows.h. No other libraries. Is there still a way to do it? Can i do it using the same principle? :)

Comment: What route are you taking? Tried WM_PAINT and WM_PRINTCLIENT yet?

Comment: Yes, by sending the target window a WM_PRINTCLIENT message and having a HDC as wParam and then trying to paint it to the main window with no success. With GetLastError() between every single line in my code it does not return anything else but zero.