# c++ Win32 Multiple windows doing same action

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have this problem. I want to open two same windows which behaviour is mirrored. So if I click on first window same action is executed on second window (mirrored behaviour). Is it possible? How can I do this? My application is in C++ and I use WinApi.

Thanks.

Comment: functional or just graphical?

Comment: This is, in general, not possible, not just for technical reasons. The best you could hope for is, that the target window supports [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). Faking input otherwise isn't going to work. Consider opening a Combo Box control. Once this action is mirrored in the second window, the first window loses its mouse capture, and the dropdown list collapses.

Comment: As in [How can i copy the visual content of a window and put it on a new window in win32 c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386312/how-can-i-copy-the-visual-content-of-a-window-and-put-it-on-a-new-window-in-win3)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, you can comunicate between them using socket, shared memory or something like that... Another way is to send all windows messages you recieve from one window to another.

Comment: Worst suggestion imaginable. [Replaying input is not the same as reprocessing it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/12/06/10375039.aspx).